# Why does Civicrm Create Mailing create it in the Scheduled state?

Tags: python, rest, civicrm

I have some Python code (using python-civicrm on Github) that creates a new Mailing in a CiviCRM/Drupal site using the external/rest.php calls. The Python code sets the 'created_id', 'name', 'subject', 'body_html' and 'body_text' attributes, as below.

The mailing is created and visible in the 'Drafts/Unscheduled' list but with the 'Scheduled' state and a schedule date of 'today'. How can I stop it doing this: I need it to be 'Unscheduled' with no scheduled date, at the moment.

This is the calling code:

```
params = {
    u'name': template.name,
    u'subject': template.subject,
    u'created_id': template.from_id,
    u'body_html': template.html,
    u'body_text': template.plain,
    u'url_tracking': u'1',
}
try:
    results = civicrm.create(u'Mailing', **params)
```

Comment: Why the downvote, and not even a comment?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer of sorts.

The API setup for creating a Mailing object in CiviCRM automatically merges into the provided call parameters a key 'api.mailing_job.create' with value '1', which is a Civi API instruction to chain creation of the mailing job once the mailing template is successful. This behaviour is intentional but is supposed to be overridable. As of now I have not discovered how to override it (over an HTTP post request).

The solution I have adopted is to delete the MailingJob by using the 'id' in the results returned from the call here:

```
civicrm_api.delete('MailingJob', results[0]['api.mailing_job.create']['values'][0]['id'])
```

Comment: @rivmey, we're trying to start a CiviCRM StackExchange site that you might be interested in. We've got more almost 300 people committed to using the site, but we're still in need of 36 people with 200+ reputation on another StackExchange site before we can launch. Would you help us out by committing: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm ? Thanks!